# Usage of 焚き付ける in this sentence

Tags: grammar, words

The topic is Gilgamesh here.

> 「英霊の座」スレ住民。タンクトップにジャージのズボン、バンダナに指抜きグローブ姿の立派な引きこもりニートで、その上セイバーのストーカーでもある。遠坂邸に居候しており、カソックにフリルのエプロン姿の家政婦のおじさんが生活全般の面倒を見ている。
>   いつも自信満々に全く説得力皆無のアドバイスを戦車男に焚き付けては、そのたびに幼馴染のエルキドゥちゃんから厳しくつっこまれるのが日常風景。
>
> 「英霊の座」スレ住民。
>   I think it's something like: People who frequent the thread 「英霊の座」, so 
>   He frequents this thread.
>
> タンクトップにジャージのズボン、バンダナに指抜きグローブ姿の立派な引きこもりニートで、その上セイバーのストーカーでもある。
>   He wears a Tank top and Jersey pants, a bandana and finger-less gloves with an appeareance like a true Hikikomori Neet, on top of that he stalks Saber.
>
> 遠坂邸に居候しており、カソックにフリルのエプロン姿の家政婦のおじさんが生活全般の面倒を見ている。
>   He lives as a freeload at Tohsaka Mansion and an old man with the appeareance of a priest robe looks after every needs he has.

戦車男:It's a person.

> いつも自信満々に全く説得力皆無のアドバイスを戦車男に焚き付けては、そのたびに幼馴染のエルキドゥちゃんから厳しくつっこまれるのが日常風景。

A:Always confidently inciting 戦車男 with useless advices and every time getting harshly interrupted by his childood friend. This is his daily life.

Or

B:Always confidently being incited by 戦車男's useless advices, he gets scolded harshly by his childood friend. This is his daily life.

I am not sure if 焚き付ける here means: Instigate someone with a piece of advice or being instigated because of a piece of advice.

Edit. 
I think it's the first one, but I am not sure.

Comment: Given the names (Gilgamesh, Saber, Tohsaka) I'm guessing this relates to Fate/stay night.

Comment: ...Yep. From Googling, it appears to be from [this Japanese Type-Moon wiki page](https://typemoon.wiki.cre.jp/wiki/%E3%82%AE%E3%83%AB%E3%82%AC%E3%83%A1%E3%83%83%E3%82%B7%E3%83%A5#.E7.99.BB.E5.A0.B4.E4.BD.9C.E5.93.81.E3.81.A8.E5.BD.B9.E6.9F.84) in the section that talks about his role/appearance in [Sensha Otoko](http://typemoon.wikia.com/wiki/Sensha_Otoko)...

Comment: Yes, it's that page. 
I already read the VN but since I can't find magazines and such here I though I might check the wiki page.

Comment: 焚き付ける is active, not passive. So it's the first one.

Comment: @user4092: You should leave that as an answer to the question, not as a comment :)

Answer (score -1):

In this case, it means "to instigate" or "to incite".

There is an etymological clue in the interesting kanji 焚き付ける. In the old days in Japan, a bath was heated by placing firewood underneath the filled tub and setting it on fire. The fire heated the water, so it was literally 焚く(build a fire) and 付ける (light it). So originally it had a sense of placing a fire underneath something. This phrase later became an idiom used when someone is urged or incited to do something. By 'lighting a fire under them', you are inciting them to action.

Here's an example from goo:
若者を焚き付けて運動を起こさせる　to stir the youth into doing some exercise

Comment: Where is this "bath" hidden in this "etymological clue"? No "water" being heated either in the ideogram. The verb itself is pretty universally used in the same way across many languages. See for example "to kindle" in English. Same direct and figurative meaning. And all that without any bathtub; the same fire can be used to roast a loser from an enemy tribe.

Comment: Ignoring the rudeness and arrogance of your comment for a moment, I was pointing out that one of the connotations the phrase originally had was a sense of placing fire under something.